# Alternative to MarkupExtension inheritance in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, markup-extensions

I'm using MarkupExtension inheritance in my WPF app, which I'd like to port under Silverlight.

I've made a "Locale" markup extension which can be used like this in xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{ui:Locale aRandomId,'My default translation'}" />
```

In fact, this MarkupExtension is binding the property its applied on to the string "My default translation", or, if found, to a sentence stored in a database named "aRandomId".

This MarkupExtension allows me to dynamicaly change my UI's locale (the markupextension is registering to a weak event 'LocaleChanged' which triggers update of every property bound with it)

**As we cannot inherit from MarkupExtension in Silverlight, I'd like to know if there is some mechanism which could replace it.**

Thanks.

*PS : I can provide the source of this MarkupExtension if needed.*

Answer (score 0):

For that exact purpose, I'm using a Converter and a ConverterParam:

[MSDN Binding.Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28VS.95%29.aspx)

It's quite easy to do, but it feels very boilerplate when you begin to have a lot of them in your app.

**Update:**
Maybe I'm overcomplicating your needs... In my apps, I have two usage patterns, one with a Converter and one without. In the simplest case, I just want to pull a string for the localized dictionary, and it looks like:

```
Text="{Binding Localization[my_string_key], Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
```

Comment: ... But Converters cannot make properties to update on event : They have a passive behavior.

Comment: Well, they don't change anything to the binding, so if your binded property changes, the text will change, passing again through the converter.

Comment: I'm loading my localization file dynamically, and I can assure you, the text changes from 'LOCALE ERROR' to the proper value.

Comment: Okay... I apologize : I think I finally figured out what you meant. But this approach is a little bit tricky : It obliges the coder to add propert(y|ies) which the UI has to be bound to : I'm willing to make my translatable sentences declared only in xaml, with no property or code behind in the model part.

Comment: Well, to better explain what I've got: I have a Dictionary of string-string key-value pairs, which is declared in my ViewModelLocator. So I only have a single binding target.

Answer (score 0):

I know this will get a lot of traditional answers, but I would also like to put forward something completely original we tried (and succeeded) doing ourselves for more efficient localisation of Silverlight using Attached Properties instead of binding:

### [Link: *Localisation of Silverlight projects after completion*](http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?cat=23)

We found resources and binding solutions to be tedious and not flexible as they all require the translations to be set in the project (and therefore needs a re-deploy of the app when it changed).

Also the selected language hardy ever changes and when it does it is all strings at once. Carrying the overhead of bindings for that purpose seems insane when you can just regenerate the current page if the language changes.

Traditionally translations are sent out in batches and managed by language (with unique keys, translator notes etc) so we found this a much better fit there too.

Our solution means we manage the localisation in a central server database but can also provide localisation editor, within the application itself, for translators to use while using the application.

- Central repository for any number of languages
- Change language by downloading new data (max 200kb per language on large app)
- Only download language required and change on the fly
- Supports in-app editing of resources by translators (does require extra UI forms).

Comment: ... interesting : waiting for part 3 ;)
My only regret is the "effort" which HAS to be made by the developper : Providing an ID for each page (reminding this kind of thing everytime I create a page is pretty hard)

Comment: (You are the first to actually ask for page 3, so may actually publish it now :)) We actually generate the page ids with the same tool that parsed out our initial "programmer English" into the database to pre-populate it. The ID is only required for the interactive editing and is not required for the translation (only the really cool extras).

Comment: It's on my *TODO* list (quite a long list at the moment) :)

Comment: Well... I can definitively understand that ! Good luck